# Not redirecting on successful login

Tags: php, html, sql

I have completed a login form and it works 100% on my WAMP server. However when I run it on a live server everything works 100%, apart from when I log in it does not redirect my page to the page it should (just displays a blank HTML page). It is however logged in, because if I enter the url of the page it should go, it displays like it should. The path to the file is correct. I hope my problem is clear. Here is the code for my login form:

```
<?php 
include_once "includes/scripts.php";
session_start();
include_once ("includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header('location: admin_cms.php');
    exit();
} else {
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        if(empty($username) or empty($password)) {
             $error = '<p>NOTE: Fields are blank</p>';  
        } else {
             $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password =?");
             $query->bindValue(1, $username);
             $query->bindValue(2, $password);
             $query->execute();
             $num = $query->rowCount();

             if($num == 1) {
                 $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                 header('location: admin_cms.php');
                 exit();
             } else {
                 $error = "<p>NOTE: The username or password is incorrect</p>";     
             }
        }
    }
?>
    <div id="login_container">
        <br><img src="images/camelhorst_logo_full.png" style="margin-top:38px;">
        <h1>LOGIN<img src="images/three_column_grid_line.png" alt="line"></h1>
        <form  acton = "admin.php" method="post" autocompleate="off">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Username" required autocomplete="off">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required autocomplete="off">
            <input type="submit"  value="Login" name="submit_login">
        </form>
<?php 
      if(isset($error)) {
          echo $error;
      }
?>
      <p id="copyright_admin"> © CAMELHORSE CREATIVE STUDIO 2013 </p>
    </div><!--login_container-->
<?php 
 } 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The session_start() MUST be at the very top of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the

```
session_start()
```

must be at the very top of the page. There can be nothing, no whitespace before it.

Secondly,

```
if (empty($username) or empty($password)){
```

needs to be replaced with this

```
if (empty($username) || empty($password)){
```

Try that and see if it works

Also, this is a bit off topic and I'm sure that it's not what's causing your problem, but md5() is very outdated. Try using

```
sha1();
```

for encryption instead. sha1() is also a bit old, but it's better than md5().

This too, is kind of off topic. But, it seems notable. You have

```
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
        $error = '<p>NOTE: Fields are blank</p>';   
    }
```

By default, md5 returns a 32 character hex number even if the value of what's being encrypted is empty. So, the condition

```
empty($password)
```

is kind of redundant. What's better to have is this:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $pass_enc = md5($_POST['password']);

    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
        $error = '<p>NOTE: Fields are blank</p>';   
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it! Have changes encryption as well i just used it because WordPress uses it haven really looked into any other encryption!

Answer (score 1):

change redirection to this.

```
echo "<script>window.location='admin_cms.php'<script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Most times, when your header() redirection fails, it is because there has been previous output (even a whitespace matters here), so you may need to be sure there has been no previous output on the file or any included files.

```
<?php include_once "includes/scripts.php"; ?>

include_once ("includes/connect.php");
```

NB: Any space outside the <?php ?> tags is considered output.
E.g.

```
<?php ...some php code... '
  //space below causes output to be written to html
?>

<?php
   ...more php code here...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iqbal Malik is right. you should use 
     echo "window.location='admin_cms.php'";

for the redirection however if you want to keep the header() thing you must put

```
 ob_start()
```

on top of the page, right under

```
 session_start()
```

it will work like a charm.

edit: 
About the md5 / sha1 thing, Ijust started using:

```
 hash("sha512", md5($password))
```

for my password encryption.